# Is there an API for obtaining the next node information in camunda7

Tags: camunda

When the process reaches the countersigning node, parameters need to be set in advance. This parameter was passed to us by another system, so we need to know when we need to pass it. So, may I ask if Camunda has an API to obtain the parameters required for the next node:

Currently, the next node is obtained by traversing the bpmnModel, but problems can arise when faced with complex bpm
//Obtain the next node information and fill in the corresponding parameters  getmap（xxxx）；
taskService.setVariablesLocal(Task, map);
taskService.complete(Task, map);

Comment: Could you please try to provide a consistent example? You are talking about countersigning tasks and signers lists ... but the example bpmn provided just has "test" tasks, so I have no real idea what problem you are trying to solve in the first place.

Comment: Before executing taskService.complete, if the next node is a countersigning task, it is necessary to set the "singerList" parameter. If not set, an error will occur. I need to know the information of the next node to set the corresponding "singerList "parameter,The getNextUserNodeForSigner method retrieves the information of the next node by traversing the current node information in the deployment bpmn flowchart. However, this method may encounter problems in certain scenarios,such as sub processes, so i 
 want finding a stable way to obtain the information of the next node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for explaining your use case. Unfortunately, there is no way to find out the next activity in a BPMN process reliably.
As you stated, for rather trivial cases, it might be possible to parse the model and derive the next node, but using non trivial models, this will fail ... there could be an intermediate message receiver involved, an error handler, a loop, a condition ... you have to rely on the engine executing your model.

To solve your particular problem (without digging deeper) it might be an option to initialize the signer list variable with an empty value before entering the multi-instance task, or make the whole embedded subprocess multi instance an use a condition (on the loop or using a conditional interrupting boundary event) to stop when the signers have been set. But this would require more discussion and is maybe better suited for the [forum](https://forum.camunda.org) than SO.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am planning to try setting default values before node execution and manually adding and subtracting signer after execution is completed